# iOS swift Post request

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, post

So I want to create a post request with the following output:

```
"user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

Instead I get:

```
{"user[password_confirmation]"=>"[FILTERED]", "user[email]"=>"test@test.com", "user[password]"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{}}
```

This is the code I use to make this post request:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let params = ["user[email]":username.text!, "user[password]":password.text!, "user[password_confirmation]":passwordRepeated.text!]

        request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in

            print(request.HTTPBody)
            print(params)
            print(error)
            print(response)
            print(data)
        })

        task.resume()
```

So how do I correctly create my params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are composing params incorrectly.

Do it like this,

```
   let params = [
        "user": [
            "email": username.text!,
            "password": password.text!,
            "password_confirmation": passwordRepeated.text!
        ]
    ]
```